# Post HiddenField values to controller with model .net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

```
var tags = M.Chips.getInstance($('.chips')).chipsData;
 var sendTags = JSON.stringify(tags, null, 2);
 $('#Tags').val(sendTags);
```

with the above method I stored chips data to hiddenfileds with .onSubmit() method. But at controller level, couldn't get them.

I'am expecting hiddenfiled chips data at contorller level along with other model property.

Comment: Please show more code, I can't understand you clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> But at controller level, couldn't get them.

If you want to get the hiddenfileds, I have a suggestion like below:

You can create a hidden input, and use name attribute to bind the data.

```
<input id="Tags" name="tags" type="hidden" />
```

The demo like below, you can refer to it:

Privacy view:

```
<form asp-action="Privacy" method="post">
    <input id="Tags" name="tags" type="hidden" />
    <input  type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var tags = {
        'x1': 1,
        'x2': 2
    }
    var sendTags = JSON.stringify(tags, null, 2);
    $('#Tags').val(sendTags);
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Privacy( string tags )
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]